# Plot multiple functions from a data file in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot several functions on the same plot on gnuplot using file data. One way of doing this is:

```
set multiplot
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2
plot 'data.dat' using 1:3
...
```

I want to know if there is a quicker way to do it. I have to plot around 10 functions on the same plot and that can get slow. Something like that would be ideal:

```
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2, using 1:3, using 1:4, ... using 1:n with lines
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's almost correct, just use

```
set style data lines
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2, '' using 1:3, '' using 1:4
```

This doesn't require `multiplot` mode.

With version 4.6 you can also iterate over the columns:

```
plot for [i=2:4] 'data.dat' using 1:i
```